# Where clause Linq not finding column

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code that checks through a questions list and then applies a method of Gettypedanswer to a column. Subsequently, another column in the linq query is created (which is already a list).
However, it seems to be adding the new value to the entire dataset as opposed to just the question in the foreach loop. For example I have 10 records and each time it grabs a newly created object answer it applies that to all 10 records instead of just the one it’s working on in the loop.

I maybe wrong but thought if I add a where clause and pass in the questionid for the one that is getting worked it should pick up the correct record (.where(questionId = question.QuestionId). Unfortunately it doesn’t work as it can’t find the column questionId even though it exists within the select:

```
foreach (var question in questions)
{
    object answer = question.GetTypedAnswer();
    
    //ConvertedAnswer is the new column 
    questions = questions.Select(q => new Question { Answer = q.Answer, AnswerType = q.AnswerType, QuestionId = q.QuestionId, ConvertedAnswer = Convert.ToString(answer) }).ToList();
     
    // Add questions to a new list of final questions to be returned.
    finalquestions.AddRange(questions);
}
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: It doesn't seem right that you replace the collection you have in `questions` with a new collection. What is the type of `questions` and what is the type of `finalquestions` and why are you setting the property ConvertedAnswer in all Question instances to the same value, in a loop?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, you should never try to modify the list you're iterating over. That is, do not insert, remove or reassign the `questions` variable inside the foreach.

Based on your code, if you only want to set another property to the current question, you could just set it like this:

```
foreach (var question in questions)
{
    object answer = question.GetTypedAnswer();
    
    question.ConvertedAnswer = Convert.ToString(answer);
}
```

This example alters each item in the list - not the list itself, as I mentioned earlier you shouldn't. It also removes the necessity to create a list of `finalquestions`.

If you do need to project your `questions` into a `finalquestions` list, you could create it as such:

```
var finalquestions = (from question in questions
                     let answer = question.GetTypedAnswer();
                     select new Question 
                     {
                          Answer = q.Answer, 
                          AnswerType = q.AnswerType, 
                          QuestionId = q.QuestionId, 
                          ConvertedAnswer = Convert.ToString(answer) 
                     }).ToList();
```

I do think query syntax add clarity here, but if you prefer method chaining, the equivalent is:

```
var finalquestions = questions
    .Select(question => new { question, answer = question.GetTypedAnswer() })
    .Select(x => new Question 
        {
            Answer = x.question.Answer, 
            AnswerType = x.question.AnswerType, 
            QuestionId = x.question.QuestionId, 
            ConvertedAnswer = Convert.ToString(x.answer) 
        })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, apologies I should of known better, just couldn't get my head around it - added breakpoints and couldn't see a better way of doing it.  You are right, the one line question.ConvertedAnswer = Convert.ToString(answer); is sufficient and I really should of done this initially.  I very much appreciate your help.